# VAST 3.0 Video Ad Server Examples?

Tags: xml, video, ads, vast

There are alot of Vast 2.0 Players and a few 3.0 complaint players, but in the iab documentation for vast 3.0, there are not alot of direct definitions or examples on sendind ad data as an ad server. Are there any website with solid examples for linear, non-linear and companion ads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kaltura tends to be one of the few players that is willing to play with new VPAID tech, so it's worth checking out their VAST 3.0 ad-pods here:
http://player.kaltura.com/modules/KalturaSupport/tests/AdPodsVast3.html

Also worth checking this page which demonstrates the events flow: 
http://player.kaltura.com/modules/KalturaSupport/tests/AdEventsVast.qunit.html